# NUXT 3: How to use route middleware in a layout? (Can I?)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've been looking to use Nuxt middleware in a layout. But I am not sure if I even can, however, since I used it in **Nuxt 2**, it may be possible in **Nuxt 3**.

The project has 2 different layouts: `Public.vue` and `Admin.vue`. I only want to use the middleware in pages that consume the **Admin layout**. Because the pages that use it should be accessed only by logged-in users, and it will be checked inside the middleware.

I tried this (doesn't work):

Admin layout | Admin.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <client-only>
      <admin-header />
    </client-only>
    <main>
      <slot />
    </main>
    <client-only>
      <admin-footer />
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import AdminHeader from "~~/components/admin/Header.vue"
import AdminFooter from "~~/components/admin/Footer.vue"

definePageMeta({
  middleware: "admin-auth"
});
</script>
```

Middleware | adminAuth.ts

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    console.log(to);
    console.log("Acessando o admin auth middleware");
})
```

Comment: Is your file in `middleware` directory? Maybe try to name it `admin-auth`, not sure if this may help. This seems to work pretty well: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/examples/routing/middleware But yeah, client side middleware is feasible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cant. Middleware only works for pages.

Instead, make a parent Page component with the auth middleware and `NuxtPage` component inside the template. See the Nuxt 3 docs for more information on [nested routes](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#nested-routes).

Example:

**/pages/admin.vue** (route => */admin*)

```
<template>
  // you can add auth based components as well
  <NuxtPage />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  definePageMeta({
     middleware: "admin-auth"
  });
</script>
```

**/pages/admin** (folder)

> All other components inside admin folder will use your auth middleware

admin/order.vue route =>   */admin/orders*

admin/page.vue route =>   */admin/some-route*

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure that you can apply a middleware to a layout.

Comment: let me know how it is possible please

Comment: You are right. After some research, I found the same answer but forgot to write here. That's a shame...

Comment: how to call global middlewares?

Comment: `<NuxtChild />` is not used in Nuxt 3. See: https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/pages-and-layouts#migration-2

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to use middleware in layout because middleware only can be use in pages, but you can try to use this method.

Create a global middleware by declaring `.global` suffix after your middleware file name for example `auth.global.ts`.

In `auth.global.ts` file you can use layout meta as your logic to simulate as if the middleware is in your layout setup.

Sample logic is like this

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    const user = useUserStore();
    
    if (!user && to.meta.layout === auth) {
        return navigateTo("/login");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `to.meta.layout` is a string, so needs to be `=== 'auth'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.global` to the middleware for it to apply to all pages.
so change your filename to `/middleware/adminAuth.global.ts`

See here https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware

Answer (score 0):

Added a file called `router.global.ts`

added to `/src/middleware/router.global.ts`

router.global.ts content:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to) => {
    if (to.fullPath.includes('+')) to.fullPath = to.fullPath.replace(/\+/g, '%20');
});
```

`nuxt.config.ts` add:

```
router: {
     middleware: ['router'],
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i was personally struggling with the layoutTransition `{ name }`, i discovered a possibility to set it using the `useRoute()` like this:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, nextTick } from "vue";

definePageMeta({
  layout: "lay1",
  layoutTransition: {
    name: "slide-left",
  },
});

const sw = () => {
  const route = useRoute();

  if (route.meta.layout === "lay2") {
    route.meta.layoutTransition = { name: "slide-left" };
    nextTick(() => {
      setPageLayout("lay1");
    });
  } else {
    route.meta.layoutTransition = { name: "slide-right" };
    nextTick(() => {
      setPageLayout("lay2");
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with **auth.global.ts** been render on server side.
So I put a **client side validation** and a trick (**{ external: true }**) on navigateTo redirect (because redirect to page with diferent layout cause style bugs):

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {

    if (process.client) {
        const user = UtilsUser.user //Get from localStorage.getItem('user')

        if (!user && to.meta.layout === 'profile') {
            //Prevent Loop:
            if (to.path !== '/auth/login') {
                return navigateTo('/auth/login', { external: true })
            }
        }
    }

})
```